# Image map to navigate on SVG document

Tags: image, navigation, svg, vector-graphics

I have a huge SVG document and I would like to be able to quickly navigate on this document using an accompanying thumbnail image, just like an image map with clickable areas . Like [Photoshop's Navigator palette](http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/10.0/help.html?content=WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-74dc.html) (thx Phrogz)

The problem is that I have no idea how to navigate on the SVG document...

I was thinking of using named `<g>` tags in my SVG document that would be the link between the image to the SVG. Something like that.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you really want distinct clickable areas (like a country map, clicking on each state), or do you want something like [Photoshop's Navigator palette](http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/10.0/help.html?content=WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-74dc.html), where a small box shows your location within the overall image?

Comment: Yes, I'd like it exactly like Photoshop's navigator palette. I was thinking about using a tag like this in my SVG: <g id="someLoc"> , and using a link on some image areas like  <a href="doc.svg#someLoc></a>, but that doesnt work. Anything straightforward similar or more coding is needed ? Thx, antoine

Comment: The navigator palette isn't like an image map. There aren't distinct hyperlinks. It uses the pixel placement of the zoom rect in the overall thumbnail to adjust the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to accomplish this. Here's what I would do:

1. Place your SVG contents in an `<svg>` element within your document.
2. Draw a rectangle over your thumbnail (which you might rasterize if your SVG file has a lot of data and drawing it scaled down causes poor performance).
3. Use JavaScript to detect clicks/drags in the thumbnail and move the rectangle over it.
4. Based on the ratio of the rectangle's placement with respect to the thumbnail, adjust the `viewBox` attribute on your SVG contents.

Actually, if it were me, I'd [embed my SVG in XHTML](http://phrogz.net/SVG/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml) and use one SVG document for the contents and either another SVG document for the thumbnail palette, or even just an HTML image and bordered div for the thumbnail.

Comment: Thank you very much Phrogz for your answer, I think I will have to write more code than expecting. I found an example that might do the trick: carto.net/papers/svg/navigationTools/index.svg , I will just have to change the JPG image to SVG